# Visual C# - DataGridView.ClearSelection() no se ejecuta (al parecer)

Tags: c#

¡Hola!
Dispongo de un TabControl con varias TabPages. En cada TabPage tengo un DataGridView al que se le agregan filas desde una base de datos usando DataGridView.Rows.Add(). Una vez que el DataGridView se llena de filas, utilizo DataGridView.ClearSelection(), sin embargo, los DataGridView muestran la primera fila seleccionada, salvo el DataGridView que está en el TabPage que aparece seleccionado por defecto, y que se muestra primeramente. He intentado usar DataGridView.ClearSelection() en el evento Selected del TabControl, para cada tabPage, sin embargo, la primera vez que selecciono un TabPage, DataGridView.ClearSelection() no funciona. Lo raro para mí es que la segunda vez que selecciono cada TabPage entonces ya funciona DataGridView.ClearSelection(). ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: quizas solo sea pro evento en el que lo estas llamando, puedes usar algun evento como el focus para saber en que tabpage estast y seleccionar la primera fila

Comment: Pero hay un solo DataGridView para todos los TabPage? o hay uno diferente por cada Page?

Comment: Un DataGridView por cada TabPage. Uso ClearSelection en el evento Load. Prové también, como ya mencioné, en el evento Selected, y nada.